# Bring ints that are even to the froont of the array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to arrange the `array` such that **even numbers** are brought **ahead.** This is what I've done.

```
    public int[] moveEvenToFront(int[] arr) {

                arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far

Comment: `it needs to be a new array not modified` - in that case, why are you modifying the original array?

Comment: im not sure how to create a new one

Comment: Down-voting purely based on the *exceedingly* bad spacing of that first line of text: *"mak ean array with th eocde and eve n ti the front"* Are you trying to make it look like [pig latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin)?

Comment: This question has a *weird* edit history. Version 1 was much clearer than version 7 (which is the current version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple. Just create a new array, then loop through the original twice. The first time, add the evens. The next time, add the odds. Looks like you were almost there:

```
public int[] moveEvenToFront(int[] arr) {

    //declare a new array to populate with the result
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];
    int temp = 0;

    //add the evens
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            result[temp] = arr[i];
            temp++;
        }
    }

    //add the odds
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            result[temp] = arr[i];
            temp++;
        }
    }

    //return
    return result;
}
```